# Check Input Text Match Flash Not Working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Could someone please help me out and tell me why on earth this doesn't work??

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,check);
function check(e:Event){
    if(input.text=="abc"){
        trace("yes");
    }
}
```

"yes" should be traced after typing "abc" into the "input" input text field.

Update:

This code works for some reason

```
input.text="abc";
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,check);
function check(e:Event){
    if(input.text=="abc"){
        trace("yes");
    }
}
```

Even though "yes" is not traced after typing "abc" into the text field.

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked as expected. I would double check to make sure you have named the TextInput component correctly (input). Also make sure you are publishing your movie to ActionScript 3. You may also want to try restarting your computer, sometimes Flash gets confused.

Comment: @user3277549 The text field is of type input, and it is being published as an AS3 file. I have absolutely no idea why it's not working. Flash has been acting strangely for me lately.

Comment: For debugging purposes, add this right before the if statement and tell us what it's outputting: `trace(input.text);`

Comment: The trace is working the way it's supposed to @Pikamander2. I don't understand why the code isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, for some reason whenever I create an Input Text Field on Flash it starts off with an extra line. Other people have had this problem too:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1008860
http://www.codingforums.com/flash-actionscript/262088-removing-extra-line-multiline-input-text-as3.html
I had been wondering why the trace would add another mysterious line after "abc", and that's why. After two days of struggling I finally figured it out. One can solve this problem by:

```
input.text="";
```

Or by setting the text field type to single line.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason for this not to work. Any ways, you can try adding Event.CHANGE event to the text field (must be input), which will be triggered when the user changes the input value.

In the handler you can trace the value of the text field and check what's going on.

Comment: I like your idea of Event.CHANGE, and I also have no idea why it's not working. I can't try tracing the textfield yet as I currently don't have access to Flash, but I'll give it a shot the next oportunity I get.

Comment: I'm about to go crazy. I started a fresh AS3 file with this code: stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,check);
function check(e:Event){
    trace(input.text);
 if(input.text=="abc"){
        trace("yes");
    }
} and an input text field with instance name "input" and it still doesn't work!!!!!

Comment: It's tracing "abc" but it still won't trace yes